# Discontinuous function prove

Tags: continuity

I want to find an answer to this case
If function f is discontinuous then √f is discontinuous.
I am trying to disprove it and I put counter examples but it seems correct.
Is this true? Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way: if $\sqrt f$ is continuous, then $f$ is continuous. This is clearly true, as the product of continuous functions is continuous (of course, you should start by saying that you are working over real numbers, that $f$ is positive, etc ...)

Comment: you mean by contrapositive?

Comment: Yes. When looking at statement involving concepts such as "discontinuous", "infinite", "irreducible", defined as a negation of another property, it is often easier to look at the contrapositive because you can actually *use* those definitions directly.

Comment: yes i was thinking about contrapositive but i was not sure about it because i put if |f| is continuous then f is continuous but it is not true that if f is discontinuous then |f| is discontinuous

Comment: That is false: take the function $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, mapping $x$ to $-1$ if it is negative, and to $1$ otherwise. Then $|f|$ is constant (and so it is continuous) but $f$ is discontinuous at $0$. An implication and its contrapositive are completely equivalent logical statement.

Comment: yes i said it is not true that if f is discontinuous then |f| is discontinuous and i used the same counter example to prove it. I was talking about the contrapositive.

Comment: if |f|  is continuous then f is continuos

Comment: Your two statements are *both* false. An implication and its contrapositive *always* have the same logical value (they are both True, or both False). I am not sure to understand what you are talking about ... The initial question about $\sqrt(f)$ is True - proved using the contrapositive - and the ones about $|f|$ are False.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118986/discussion-between-lama-bitar-and-numbra).

Answer (score 0):

If squeezing of the domain is allowed then this is your counterexample:

$f(x)= 1$ for $x>0$ and $f(x)= -1$ for $x\le0$ which is discontinuous but the square root of it i.e. $\sqrt{f(x)}$ is continuous on its domain.

Comment: it is true why we put counter example?

Comment: As I said in answer , if squeezing of domain $f(x)$ is allowed.